# Can't delete node in Firebase Database Console Bug

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete a node in Firebase console, but for some reason it is not being deleted. Please see video. https://youtu.be/jHHg8P6FOTI

Comment: If you're having problems with the Firebase console, please contact Firebase support directly.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: did you tried another browser ?

Comment: My first step would be to check the output in the JavaScript console in your browser. Also: make sure you disable all extensions/plug-ins, as they may interfere.

Comment: @GastónSaillén I tried Chrome, Safari, Firefox,